# How to skip some part of Regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have some pdf file, and the program reads it line by line.

Here is snipped from a file:

[image]

I need to extract:

> 12000

The parsed line looks like the following:

> Bolighus fullverdi 4 374 720 12 000 11 806

I can't find a way how to skip first 7 numbers (`4 374 720`).

I tried to play with some matching like:

> (\d+ ){3}

It founds 2 matches:

[image]

Regex how to get value at this case:

> \d+ 000

But I want to omit `000` from the regex. In different documents, it will fail.

***How to solve this issue?***

Maybe you can suggest some other solution to this problem?

**UPDATE:**

With @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi answer everything is mostly done:

```
public static String groupNumbers(String pageLine) {
    String transformedLine = pageLine.replaceAll(" (?=\\d{3})", StringUtils.EMPTY);
    log.info("TRANSFORMED LINE: \n[{}]\nFrom ORIGINAL: \n[{}]", transformedLine, pageLine);
    return transformedLine;
}

public static List<String> getGroupedNumbersFromLine(String pageLine) {
    String groupedLine = groupNumbers(pageLine);
    List<String> numbers = Arrays.stream(groupedLine.split(" "))
            .filter(StringUtils::isNumeric)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    log.info("Get list of numbers: \n{}\nFrom line: \n[{}]", numbers, pageLine);
    return numbers;
}
```

However, I found one critical issue.

Sometimes pdf file can look like the following:

[image]

Where last 3 digits is a separate number.

And parsed line ends with:

> 313 400 6 000 370

Which produces an incorrect result:

> 313400, 6000370

instead of

> 313400, 6000, 370

**UPDATE 2**

Consider the next case:

[image]

Our line will look like:

> Innbo Ekstra Nordea 1 500 000 1 302

it will produce 3 groups as a result:

> 1500000
>   1
>   302

In fact, we have only a second group is missing from input.
***Is it possible to make a regex more flexible if the second group is missing?***

How to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Skipping the first 7 numbers is an unreliable way to do it as it looks like its possible for it to be 6 or 8, you should change the way you parse it, 

However if you're convinced that the length of the numbers will stay the same "(\s\d{2}\s\d{3}\s)" would work

Comment: The problem really is that there is no firm delimiter. Is there maybe a numerical relationship (such as subtotal = unit price * quantity)? It seems that you can exploit the fact that `totalpris = naturkadepremie + pris per ar`

Comment: you could do two steps, one to get rid of the strings in the front, and if the seven digits number doesn't change in length, you can truncate them in the second step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers have a special pattern which can be used to hack the problem for you. If you notice, any space in this string which is followed by exactly three digits can be removed to unite the number forming actual number, which will make this string,

```
Bolighus fullverdi 4 374 720 12 000 11 806
```

to this,

```
Bolighus fullverdi 4374720 12000 11806
```

And thus you can capture the second number easily by using this regex,

```
.*\d+\s+(\d+)\s+\d+
```

and capture group 2.

Here is a sample java code for same,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Bolighus fullverdi 4 374 720 12 000 11 806";
    s = s.replaceAll(" (?=\\d{3})", "");
    System.out.println("Transformed string: " + s);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\d+\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Didn't match");
    }
}
```

Which outputs,

```
Transformed string: Bolighus fullverdi 4374720 12000 11806
12000
```

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Here is the explanation for this regex `\D*\d+\s+(\d+)\s+\d+` for capturing required data from transformed string.

```
Bolighus fullverdi 4374720 12000 11806
```

- `.*` --> Matches any data before the numbers and here it matches `Bolighus fullverdi`
- `\d+` --> Matches one or more digits and here it matches `4374720`
- `\s+` --> Matches one or more space which is present between the numbers.
- `(\d+)` --> Matches one or more digits and captures it in group 1 where it matches `12000`
- `\s+` --> Matches one or more space which is present between the numbers.
- `\d+` --> Matches one or more digits and here it matches `11806`

As OP wanted to capture the second number, hence I only grouped (put parenthesis around intended capture part) second \d+ but if you want to capture first number or third number, you can simply group them as well like this,

```
\D*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)
```

Then in java code, calling,

`m.group(1)` would give group 1 number which is `4374720`

`m.group(2)` would give group 2 number which is `12000`

`m.group(3)` would give group 3 number which is `11806`

Hope this clarifies and let me know if you need anything further.

**Edit2**

For covering the case for following string,

```
Andre bygninger 313 400 6 000 370
```

so that it captures 313400, 6000 and 370, I have to change the approach of the solution. And in this approach, I will not be transforming the string, but rather will capture the digits with spaces and once all three numbers are captured, will remove space between them. This solution will work for old string as well as new string above where we want to capture last three digits `370` as third number. But let's suppose we have following case,

```
Andre bygninger 313 400 6 000 370 423
```

where we have further `423` digits in the string, then it will be captured as following numbers,

> 313400, 6000370, 423

as it doesn't know whether 370 should go to 6000 or 423. So I have made the solution in a way where last three digits are captured as third number.

Here is a java code that you can use.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile(".*?(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Bolighus fullverdi 4 374 720 12 000 11 806",
            "Andre bygninger 313 400 6 000 370");

    for (String s : list) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("For string: " + s);
            System.out.println(m.group(1).replaceAll(" ", ""));
            System.out.println(m.group(2).replaceAll(" ", ""));
            System.out.println(m.group(3).replaceAll(" ", ""));
        } else {
            System.out.println("For string: '" + s + "' Didn't match");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This code prints following output as you wanted,

```
For string: Bolighus fullverdi 4 374 720 12 000 11 806
4374720
12000
11806

For string: Andre bygninger 313 400 6 000 370
313400
6000
370
```

Here is the explanation for regex,

```
.*?(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)
```

- `.*?` --> Matches and consumes any input before the numbers
- `(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)` --> This pattern tries to capture first number which can start with one to three digits followed by space and exactly three digits and "space plus three digits" altogether can occur zero or more times.
- `\\s*` --> Followed by zero or more space

And after that, same group `(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)` is repeated two more times so it can capture numbers in three groups.

Since I have made three capturing groups, hence capturing has to take place in three groups for it to be a successful match. So for e.g. here is the mechanism of capturing this input,

```
Andre bygninger 313 400 6 000 370
```

First, `.*?` matches `"Andre bygninger "`. Then first group `(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)` first matches 313 (because of `\\d{1,3}`) and then `(?:\\s+\\d{3})*` matches a space and `400` and it stops because next data followed is space followed by `6` which is just one digit and not three digit.

Similarly, second group `(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)` first matches `6` (because of `\\d{1,3}`) and then `(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)` matches `000` and stops because, it needs to leave some data for matching group 3 else regex match will fail.

Finally, third group matches `370` as that is the only data that was left. So `\\d{1,3}` matches `370` and then `(?:\\s+\\d{3})*` matches nothing as it is zero or more group.

Hope that clarifies. Let me know if you still have any query.

**Edit 22 Dec 2018 for grouping numbers in two groups only**

As you want to group the data from this string,

```
Innbo Ekstra Nordea 1 500 000 1 302
```

Into two group of numbers having `1500000` and `1302`, your regex needs to only have two groups and it becomes this like I replied in the comment,

```
.*?(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)
```

Here is the java code for same,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile(".*?(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Innbo Ekstra Nordea 1 500 000 1 302");

    for (String s : list) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("For string: " + s);
            System.out.println(m.group(1).replaceAll(" ", ""));
            System.out.println(m.group(2).replaceAll(" ", ""));
        } else {
            System.out.println("For string: '" + s + "' Didn't match");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Which prints this like you expect.

```
For string: Innbo Ekstra Nordea 1 500 000 1 302
1500000
1302
```

Comment: This is good, however if a number was in the hundred-Xs range e.g: 123 123 456 123 456 789 this would cause an issue

Comment: Well, the case you proposed, even a human can't logically figure out what to extract so machine obviously fails :) But my solution works for OP's given string. In case all numbers have 3 digits separated by space, then we may have to estimate how the pattern is of numbers and then we can come up with another solution too. I expect OP to come up with more samples where he is having trouble picking the intended number, then I can suggest another solution.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi can you explain a little bit your regex? Also, not bad to know how to take the first number from the transformed line.

Comment: @nazar_art: For sure, let me edit my answer to add explanation

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi All is good for now. However, your regex didn't work for `group(1)`. I modified it a little bit `\D*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)` and now it works fine. For the first group, it gives exactly the first number.

Comment: @nazar_art: Yes you are right. Actually I needed to use non-greedy capture in capturing text `.*?` instead of `.*` which is why `.*` matched everything leaving just one digit. Your solution of using \D* is also perfect as it will match everything except digits. Good job.

Comment: @nazar_art: Ok, sure, let me provide you a solution to cover this case as well.

Comment: @nazar_art: Had to change my approach and now it covers both old string as well as new string. Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: @nazar_art: Sure, let me add.

Comment: @nazar_art: Added explanation for new regex. Let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi How to modify regex if the second group of numbers will be missing? For now, we have 3 groups and we assume they are always present.

Comment: @nazar_art: If you just have two group of numbers, then you just need to have 2 groups in the regex. The new regex becomes `.*?(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)\\s*(\\d{1,3}(?:\\s+\\d{3})*)` Try and let me know if it works else You will have to provide me sample input.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi updated question with more details.

Comment: @nazar_art: Updated my answer for having numbers in two groups only.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi with last update question was how to make regex flexible in both cases: when the second group is presented or missed.

Comment: @nazar_art: No, you can't use a common regex for handling both the situations because logically you might be interested in capturing it either way. Either in three groups or may be in two groups. And since you are using a common regex, you can't tell the regex, which of the either ways to do it. So you can't do with a common regex due to logical limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to match the part you are interested in, it might be easier to modify the string to leave nothing but what you need.

From your question it sounds like you always have 7 digit number for the 2nd column in the table so you could include that in the regex:

```
.*\d\s\d{3}\s\d{3}\s(\d+\s+\d+)\s.*. 
^^ matches all the words from the first column  
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - matches the 7 digits and 2 spaces in the 2nd column. 
                  ^^ matches the space(s) between the columns. 
                     ^^^^^^^^^ matches the 2 sets of numbers with a space(12 000) in your example.
```

Example program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "Bolighus fullverdi 4 374 720 12 000 11 806";
    // Because it's a java string, back-slashes need to be escaped - hence the double \\
    String result = string.replaceAll(".*\\d\\s\\d{3}\\s\\d{3}\\s(\\d+\\s+\\d+)\\s+.*", "$1");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: @Bflair thank you for your answer. However, the first number can be different. Not only number with 7 digits.